# Can I fly over Schengen zone without visa?

Tags: general-aviation, easa

I don't have a Schengen visa. Am I eligible to fly over any Schengen country without landing there? Of course I mean that I take off from a non-Schengen country, and land in a non-Schengen zone as well.

Moreover, can I land somewhere in Schengen zone? For example, one touch-n-go in Schengen zone airport, and then fly back.

I consider that I fly an EASA-reg aircraft with an EASA pilot license.

Comment: As a clarification, you are not intended to fly in commercial aircraft but command your own aircraft, is that right?

Comment: Yep, just non-profit flight for fun in limits of my time building.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here you might try [travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/); they have a lot of questions about Schengen and other visa situations. Some countries do have flight crew visas, but I suspect that they're only available to professionals. Otherwise, I think it's likely the same rules will apply to you that would apply to anyone else flying commercially, but I really don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A visa is a permit to ask for permission to enter into a country by crossing its borders. Since you are not entering the country; but rather overflying it - you only need to worry about any requirements for your destination.

Now, if you are doing a technical stop, and you don't leave your aircraft - then you don't need a visa. This is true for normal passengers on commercial flights as well.

If you need to leave the aircraft, but not leave the sterile area of the airport - then depending on your nationality you may need a special crew visa (this is different than the normal visa you would get as a passenger).

For crew visas, there are no uniform rules. Each country is free to set their own permissions and requirements so you'll need to contact the embassy of the country you wish to stop in for information.

God forbid you face an emergency and have to land at a country and you don't have or don't know the visa requirements - there are provisions for such cases. Emergency permission can be provided to cross borders.

In all cases, make sure you carry a passport that is valid for at least 6 months after your return date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate any nearby flight school, they will have experience with these topics.
Or you can contact your country's aviation authority.